# Get Original Grammar Productions in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4, rules, production

Is there any API in ANTLR4 for obtaining the original productions from the grammar?

For example, if there was a rule:

`functionHeader : identifier LPAREN parameterDecl RPAREN`

... is there some function on the parse that, given the `functionHeader` token would return a list `["identifier", "LPAREN", "parameterDecl", "RPAREN"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is rarely as simple as the list of elements you specify their but you can look at the augmented transition network (ATN) via `parser.getATN()` then get the rule start state etc...See [ATNState](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/ATNState.html)